# Como contar distintos resultados de una tabla por el id de la relacion

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos tablas una llamada Parcela y otra Visita, la idea es que una parcela tiene muchas visitas, lo que quiero obtener es cuantas visitas se obtienen por cada parcela en un año.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo en la tabla tengo 3 registros de visitas y quiero generar un reporte donde diga la parcela uno tuvo 2 visitas al año y la parcela con id= 2 tuvo una visita en el año. el resultado mas o menos quedaria asi.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En una tabla, pero e intentado usando distinct desde mi consulta pero me trae como resultado dos, y me lo coloca en ambas siendo que para el primer resultado tengo 2 visitas y para el segundo solo una.
Estoy trabajando en laravel añado captura de la tabla parcela por si se requiere
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDITADO: AGREGO MODELOS, RELACIONES Y LAS MANERAS EN LA QUE LO E INTENTADO

Modelo : Visita
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Visita extends Model
{
    //
     protected $fillable = [
        'fecha','actividad','descripcion','id_parcela',
    ];

    public function parcela(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Parcela','id','id_parcela');
    }
}
```

Modelo : Parcela:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Parcela extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'latitud','longitud','altitud','ha',
        'pendiente','localidad','id_tiposuelo',
        'id_riego','id_municipio','id_productor'
    ];

    public function visitas(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Visita','id_parcela','id');
    }
    public function suelo(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\TipoSuelo','id','id_tiposuelo');
    }
    public function municipio(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Municipio','id','id_municipio');
    }
    public function productores(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Productor','id','id_productor');
    }
    public function riego(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Riego','id','id_riego');
    }
    public function plantacion(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Plantacion','id_parcela','id');
    }
}
```

Controlador donde envio los datos a mi vista(VisitaController)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 public function reporte(Request $request){

        $valor = $request->año;
        $id_parcela =$request->id;

        $visitas = Visita::whereYear('created_at', $valor)
                         ->get();

        $parcelas = Parcela::all();

        $view = view('parcelas.reporteVisitas',compact('visitas','parcelas'));

        return $view;
        // $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        // $pdf->loadHTML($view);
        // return $pdf->stream();
    }
```

Y esta es la tabla donde quiero colocar el dato en mi vista, que solo es de prueba ya que como se ve en el controlador lo mandare a un archivo PDF con dompdf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reporte de Visitas</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #pdf-titulo{
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
#socio-pdf{
  margin-left: 60px;
 vertical-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-3">
                <p align="center"><img id="socio-pdf" src="img/logo-real1.png" width="60%" height="60%"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <h2 align="center" id="pdf-titulo" >Empresa S.A de C.V</h2>
            </div>
            @foreach($visitas as $visita)
            @endforeach
                <H2 align="center">Reporte de Visitas Año: {{$visita->created_at->year}}</H2>

            <table align="center" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Propietario</th>
            <th>Localidad</th>
            <th>Municipio</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Numero de Visitas</th>
        
        </tr>

@foreach($visitas as $visita)

@endforeach
@foreach($parcelas as $parcela)
@foreach($parcela->productores as $productor)
    @endforeach
<tr>
            <td>{{$productor->nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{$parcela->localidad}}</td>
            <td>{{$parcela->municipio->nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{$parcela->municipio->estado->nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{$visita->count('id_parcela',$parcela->id)}}</td>
            
            
        </tr>
        @endforeach
            </table>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

lo intentantado tambien de la siguiente forma:

```
$count = $visita->count(DISTINCT('id_parela'); //Pero no me funciono!
```

Comment: Listo añadi mas informacion, gracias

Comment: Listo añadi el codigo en texto

Comment: Solo estoy filtrando por año

Comment: Gacias pude solucionarlo!

Comment: Si gracias, ya lo publique, gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- El número de visitas lo podemos obtener en razón de las veces que aparece registrada la llave foránea que identifica a cada parcela en la tabla de visitas.
- Dicho lo anterior, tienes las relaciones definidas (una parcela *hasMany* visitas) entonces podemos recurrir al método [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) para obtener el conteo de las relaciones que una entidad tiene asociadas.
- Del mismo modo cuando invoquemos a la relación `visitas` deberemos filtrar por la fecha, entonces podemos usar el método [`whereYear()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses)

Propuesta:

```
$consultaVisitas =  Parcela::withCount(['visitas' => function ($query) {
                        $query->whereYear('visitas.created_at', $anioBusqueda); 
                    }])->get();
```

En este punto nos haría falta añadir los datos de la entidad `Productores` y `Municipio` lo cual podemos obtener en un nuevo método [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) pasando un array de las relaciones deseadas:

```
$consultaVisitas =  Parcela::withCount(['visitas' => function ($query) {
                        $query->whereYear('visitas.created_at', $anioBusqueda); 
                    }])->with(['productores', 'municipio'])
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCION:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reporte de Visitas</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #pdf-titulo{
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
#socio-pdf{
  margin-left: 60px;
 vertical-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-3">
                <p align="center"><img id="socio-pdf" src="img/logo-real1.png" width="60%" height="60%"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <h2 align="center" id="pdf-titulo" >Empresa S.A de C.V</h2>
            </div>
            @foreach($visitas as $visita)
            @endforeach
                <H2 align="center">Reporte de Visitas Año: {{$visita->created_at->year}}</H2>

            <table align="center" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Propietario</th>
            <th>Localidad</th>
            <th>Municipio</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Numero de Visitas</th>
        
        </tr>

@foreach($visitas as $visita)

@endforeach
@foreach($parcelas as $parcela)

@php
    $contados = $visita->where('id_parcela',$parcela->id)->count();
    echo $contada;
    @endphp
@foreach($parcela->productores as $productor)
    @endforeach
<tr>
            <td>{{$productor->nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{$parcela->localidad}}</td>
            <td>{{$parcela->municipio->nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{$parcela->municipio->estado->nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{$contados}}</td>
            
            
        </tr>
        @endforeach
            </table>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```